# Compiler cant find transformLaserScanToPointCloud function

Tags: ros, laser-scan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am quite new to ROS and also programming :) and facing a problem during making executable for node for [converting laser scan to get point cloud](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_pipeline/Tutorials/IntroductionToWorkingWithLaserScannerData) from my laser scanner data. Can you please have a look on the error and tell me what can be the reason. I also added the dependencies. Everything looks to be fine. Thanks in advance.

```
CMakeFiles/my_scan_to_cloud.dir/src/tfToPointcloud.o: In function `laser_geometry::LaserProjection::transformLaserScanToPointCloud(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > const&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud_<std::allocator<void> >&, tf::Transformer&, int)':
/home/Reza/ros_workspace/laser_geometry/laser_geometry/include/laser_geometry/laser_geometry.h:212: undefined reference to `laser_geometry::LaserProjection::transformLaserScanToPointCloud_(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud_<std::allocator<void> >&, sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > const&, tf::Transformer&, double, int)'
CMakeFiles/my_scan_to_cloud.dir/src/tfToPointcloud.o: In function `LaserScanToPointCloud':
/home/Reza/ros_workspace/laser_geometry/laser_geometry/src/tfToPointcloud.cpp:22: undefined reference to `laser_geometry::LaserProjection::~LaserProjection()'
CMakeFiles/my_scan_to_cloud.dir/src/tfToPointcloud.o: In function `~LaserScanToPointCloud':
/home/Reza/ros_workspace/laser_geometry/laser_geometry/src/tfToPointcloud.cpp:8: undefined reference to `laser_geometry::LaserProjection::~LaserProjection()'
/home/Reza/ros_workspace/laser_geometry/laser_geometry/src/tfToPointcloud.cpp:8: undefined reference to `laser_geometry::LaserProjection::~LaserProjection()'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31968/compiler-cant-find-transformlaserscantopointcloud-function/) by [Reza Ch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1696/reza-ch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2012-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two possibilities: you're *sure* you've added `laser_geometry` as a `depend` in your `manifest.xml`? Like, double-plus-sure?

Another possibility: are you sure `laser_geometry` is installed? If you've done a source install (and have the dependency set), try using `rosmake` to build your package, not just `make`. If you're using a binary install, double-check that the `laser_geometry` package is installed.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/13151/rsa/) on 2014-04-12**:
I have the same problem, I downloaded the laser_geometry from the source but I have package.xml not mainfest.xml which is different somehow and I still haave the same problem when I add it to the package.xml file.. do i have to add anything in the Cmakelist